# Is it possible to initialize a form in HTML without having to initialize all the input field indipendently?

Tags: html, forms, initialization

Let's say I have a HTML form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Personal information:</legend>
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
    <br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

that generates the following string when the input is submitted:

> firstname=Mickey&lastname=Mouse

Does HTML support any kind of straightforward initialization of the form passing a similar string without having to initialize independently each input value?

Comment: Like submitting the form without the inputs?

Comment: The form might be initially empty and when the page is requested I would like to dynamically initialize the form using a custom string